# Is it possible to use nested selectors in Meteor event maps?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, meteor

Here, I would like to select the `.accept` element from within the `.header` element. Is this possible? [The documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) is inconclusive and I have tried some variations to no avail, is there a trick I'm not aware of?

```
'click .header .accept': function (event) { ... },
```

In jQuery I might use this: `$('.header .accept')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you shared will work assuming you don't have a conflict elsewhere. Try using the code below. The event fires only if you click the second div, as you want.

template:

```
<body>
    {{> page}}
</body>

<template name="page">
    <div class="header">.header 
        <div class="accept">.header .accept</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.page.events({
        'click .header .accept': function(event) {
            console.log('accept clicked');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ram1, I am sure that when I tried that before it did not work; perhaps something else was wrong that meant the event didn't fire. Anyway, it works, so thank you.