# meteor: how to use multiple classes in css selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, meteor

This works well in meteor.

```
Template.xxx.events = {
'click .btn-plus': function(event) {}
}
```

But in this example, the event were never fired.

```
Template.xxx.events = {
'click .btn.btn-success.btn-mini.btn-plus.pull-right': function(event) {}
}
```

Why you can't use multiple classes as selector? i need to identify the button on the .btn-plus class.

regards, cid

EDIT:

**My temporary solution:**

*HTML-file:*

```
<div class="btn-plus">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini pull-right">Caption</button>
</div>
```

*JS-file:*

```
Template.xxx.events = {
  'click .btn-plus': function(event) {}
}
```

Comment: Try to separate the classes with a space

Comment: This doesn't work, too. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a quick peek at the docs. I think this will work...

```
Template.xxx.events = {
    'click .btn .btn-success .btn-mini .btn-plus .pull-right': function(event) {}
}
```

Comment: Where in the sources you found this? I'm not so familiar with the meteor sources and javascript in general. ;) I tried this, but the event was never fired (I copy'n'pasted the code from my html tag and added the dots, so the sorting was given, too.)

Comment: I just hit Google and read the first link that looked promising. :)

Comment: Ok, hehe. Which search terms have you entered in google? I found only a answer about nested div's, but i can't wrap the .btn-plus class in other elements with the classes .btn, .btn-mini, etc... Isn't it so?

Comment: [The nested div's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448504/is-it-possible-to-use-nested-selectors-in-meteor-event-maps)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

```
Template.xxx.events({
   'click .btn, click .btn-success, click .btn-mini, click .btn-plus, click .pull-right': function(event) {
      console.log("clicked a button");
   }
}
```

There is another page addressing this question here: [Meteor JS: How to do I create event handler for multiple selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520798/meteor-js-how-to-do-i-create-event-handler-for-multiple-selectors)