# Meteor JS: How to do I create event handler for multiple selectors?

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

I am trying to create the same event handler for multiple elements, but cannot find anywhere in the documentation to do this. In the below example, I am trying to create a click handler for all text handings. This works for `h1`, but not for the rest.

```
Template.page.events({
  'click h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6' : function (e, template) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
Template.page.events({
  'click h1, click h2, click h3, click h4, click h5, click h6' : function (e, template) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

I believe event maps do not support comma separated selectors because [commas are used to delimit individual event names or `event selector` pairs](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps).

Comment: Ah! That worked and I wish it was a little more explicit in the Meteor docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

```js
Template.page.events({
   'click h1, click h2, click h3, click h4, click h5, click h6' : function (e, template) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

Comment: That link should now be:
http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438853/how-to-detect-events-on-entire-document-in-meteor-js) previously, which is reproduced below for handling multiple events on the entire document with a single handler:

```
Template.template_name_here.events({
  'keyup, click': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("KEYUP OR CLICK");
  }
});
```