# How to detect events on entire document in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

It's really as simple as that. I currently have in my template events, but it is not working:

```
 'keyup': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("KEYUP");
}
```

Update: it appears to be a generic bug in the framework. I would appreciate it if anyone could share a manual hack I could employ that doesn't involve using someone else's packages.

Update 2: I have solved this problem as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of a sudden my original code works. Maybe the good folks at Meteor has fixed the problem, yay!

Here's what works for me on 0.9.3.1:

```
Template.template_name_here.events({
  'keyup': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("KEYUP");
  }
});
```

Meteor can even handle multiple events with a single handler like this:

```
Template.template_name_here.events({
  'keyup, click': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("KEYUP OR CLICK");
  }
});
```

Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is a bug in meteor ([source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2024)) that events don't fire on `UI.body.template`. You can use a package [meteor-body-events](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events) to patch that, and attach `keyup` event on entire document.

Comment: I am shocked that a JavaScript framework lacks such a basic function.In tthat case e I'll revise the question to ask for manual hacks. I prefer not to use another package, but if I settle I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can also try using Jquery or rethinking your approach

Comment: How can I do it with JQuery? Where would I put the code? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to use Template.tpl.created = function() {$(window).on('keyup', function(){});};

Comment: Thanks for the tips, my friend. I have gotten it to work using my original method. Check out the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Meteor is properly handling `<body>` events, **unless** you are using a renderer which takes over rendering of the template. An example of this is [Kadira:blaze-templates](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout) which will override default Meteor rendering of template (for use with FlowRouter), or [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router).

Luckily there is a simple package to restore this functionality called [gwendall:body-events](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events).